# Specifiying checked and unchecked value for checkboxes Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I would like to create some check boxes, where they will belong to Feature Model. I know api says `check_box(object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")`. But I would like to get the name of the check box. Lets say if I have a check box `Air Conditioning`, when it is clicked I would like to get `Air Conditioning` itself.

First question how to get it and second question, how should I build the database, will it be boolean or string in this case?.

EDIT 1:

For instance, 
Does that code;

```
check_box_tag 'rock', 'rock music'
# => <input id="rock" name="rock" type="checkbox" value="rock music" />
```

Returns a string value as rock music?
Thank you

Comment: What if you have a boolean value called air_condition? Object.air_condition can then give true or false. In a form_tag you would use check_box_tag(object, :air_condition, checked: object.air_condition)

Comment: So, if I have it as boolean like you said, (`air_condition:boolean`). Then, this code for instance works?. `<p>You have selected <%= Object.air_condition %></p>`  ?

Comment: Yep. You should add a `default: false` as well. And it would only return true/false, so perhaps:
`<p>You Air condition is <%= (Object.air_condition) ? 'On' : 'Off' %></p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good to use booleans - because if you would save things as strings it gets messy if you ever want to localize and stuff.

I would add a field called `:air_condition, :boolean, default: false`.

To make it easier in your view, you can add a method in your model

```
def ac
  if air_condition
    'On'
  else
    'Off'
  end
end
```

In your view you can then use:

```
<p>You Air condition is <%= Object.ac %></p>
```

And in your form it would be

```
<% form_for(Object) do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box(:air_condition, checked: Object.air_condition) %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**Edit** 
The above solution works good if you have just a few attributes. But you do not want to edit your Object model every time you need a new attribute if you have a 100. Then you should create a new model instead: (if you object model is a Boat)

```
def Attribute << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: :attribute_boats
  has_many: :boats, through: attribute_boats

  def to_s
    title
  end
end
```

With attributes such as title:string and perhaps something else.

You then create your Join model:

```
def AttributeBoat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attribute
  belongs_to :boat

  validates :attribute_id, :boat_id, presence: true
end
```

And in your Boat-model you add:

```
has_many :attribute_boats
has_many :attributes, through: :attribute_boats
```

And then you create a normal CRUD-controller for your new Attribute model.

Then in your Boat-form you add

```
<% form_for(Object) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:attribute_ids,Attribute.all, :id, :title) %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This means that you can add new attributes without changing any of your code.

Comment: Ok, I got the point. Thank you. So if I have lets say 3 checkboxes, say, air condition, anchor, gps etc. So, the form should become;  `<% form_for(Object) do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box(:air_condition, checked: Object.air_condition) %>
  <%= f.check_box(:gps, checked: Object.gps) %>
  <%= f.check_box(:anchor, checked: Object.anchor) %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>` am I correct?

Comment: Aha, you want to have those as attributes of your object, seems like a boat. Then I understand why you want it as a string 

Comment: Exactly!. But I ll follow your way :)

Comment: Look at my updated answer, I think that would be even more dynamic 